# Pandas json_normalize and JSON flattening error

Tags: python, pandas

A panda newbie here that's struggling to understand why I'm unable to completely flatten a JSON I receive from an API. I need a Dataframe with all the data that is returned by the API, however I need all nested data to be expanded and given it's own columns for me to be able to use it.

The JSON I receive is as follows:

```
[
   {
      "query":{
         "id":"1596487766859-3594dfce3973bc19",
         "name":"test"      
      },
      "webPage":{
         "inLanguages":[
            {
               "code":"en"            
            }
         ]      
      },
      "product":{
         "name":"Test",
         "description":"Test2",
         "mainImage":"image1.jpg",
         "images":[
            "image2.jpg",
            "image3.jpg"         
         ],
         "offers":[
            {
               "price":"45.0",
               "currency":"€"            
            }
         ],
         "probability":0.9552192      
      }
    }
  ]
```

Running `pd.json_normalize(data)` without any additional parameters shows the nested values price and currency in the product.offers column. When I try to separate these out into their own columns with the following:

`pd.json_normalize(data,record_path=['product',meta['product',['offers']]])`

I end up with the following error:
`f"{js} has non list value {result} for path {spec}. "`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used this technique a few times

1. do initial `pd.json_normalize()` to discover the columns
2. build `meta` parameter by inspecting this and the original `JSON`.  NB possible index out of range here
3. you can only request one `list` drives `record_path` param
4. a few tricks `product/images` is a `list` so it gets named `0`.  rename it
5. did a Cartesian product to merge two different data frames from breaking down lists.   It's not so stable

```py
data = [{'query': {'id': '1596487766859-3594dfce3973bc19', 'name': 'test'},
  'webPage': {'inLanguages': [{'code': 'en'}]},
  'product': {'name': 'Test',
   'description': 'Test2',
   'mainImage': 'image1.jpg',
   'images': ['image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg'],
   'offers': [{'price': '45.0', 'currency': '€'}],
   'probability': 0.9552192}}]

# build default to get column names
df = pd.json_normalize(data)
# from column names build the list that gets sent to meta param
mymeta = [[s for s in c.split(".")] for c in df.columns ]
# exclude lists from meta - this will fail
mymeta = [l for l in mymeta if not isinstance(data[0][l[0]][l[1]], list)]

# you can build df from either of the product lists NOT both
df1 = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=[["product","offers"]], meta=mymeta)
df2 = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=[["product","images"]], meta=mymeta).rename(columns={0:"image"})
# want them together - you can merge them.  note columns heavily overlap so remove most columns from df2
df1.assign(foo=1).merge(
    df2.assign(foo=1).drop(columns=[c for c in df2.columns if c!="image"]), on="foo").drop(columns="foo")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Rob. Was definitely a lot more complicated than I expected, but it gives me what I need. Now to go through each step to figure out what it is exactly that you've done.